# Design Pattern: Inheritance or Composition

Tags: oop, inheritance, design-patterns, composition

I have 2 classes A and B, both of which have properties X and Y; but class B also has another property, Z. Classes A and B are completely unrelated to one another, they just share properties X and Y.

**Inheritance**

```
class A
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}

class B : A
{
    public int Z;
}
```

Class B does not have a "is-a" relationship to class A, so it breaks inheritance principals is OOP.

**Composition**

```
class A
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}

class B
{
    public A ObjA;
    public int Z;
}
```

Class B does not have a "has-a" relationship to class A so it breaks composition principals is OOP.

Without duplicate code, should I use inheritance or composition (even though they brake the principles of OOP) or is there another design pattern?  I personally think that using inheritance is going to be the lesser of the evils because of readability.

Comment: *how would I accomplish this?*: accomplish what? I can't understand what you're asking. BTW, in your second example, B **does** have a has-a relationship with A.

Comment: @JBNizet I fixed the question to make it a little more clear.  Tell me if that helps

Comment: Frankly, no, it doesn't. If I understand correctly, B doesn't have a has-a  relationship, so composition shouldn't be used, and it doesn't have a is-a association with A either, so inheritance shouldn't be used. Is that right? Then, well, don't use any of those. Make B completely unrelated to A. Just because a car has wheels and a mouse also has one doesn't mean they should be related. Maybe if you gave a concrete example with real classes, we could provide more help.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes you are correct.  A and B are completely unrelated, but they share similar properties X and Y.  But making the classes completely unrelated means having properties X and Y duplicate in each class.

Comment: That's not a problem. String has a length. List has a Length. Line has a length. They are totally unrelated and have their own length. Duplication of two fields is way better than introducing an artificial relationship that should not exist.

Comment: @THEStephenStanton In your example, X and Y are completely trivial and easy to duplicate in different places. If they are actually complicated, like entire classes, they should themselves be separate objects and be has-a relationships within the containing classes. Just because classes have similar properties does not mean they should use inheritance or composition. Still OO.

Comment: @JBNizet I see what you're saying.  So say I have a class Paper that has properties Height and Width and I have a class Boat that also has properties Height and Width but also has Length, I should just duplicate the Height and Width properties in each class? Even if I have special rounding rules for height and width that would get duplicated in each class?

Comment: If you have special rounding rules for `Height` and `Width` then _that_ should be a separate class (`Size`) that both `Paper` and `Boat` contain.

Comment: @DStanley I noticed that in that example I gave with Boat and Paper, in my actual code, though, it is a little more complex and readability would be hard if I had a base class like that.  I think that duplication would be best in this case.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Agreed, but I don't like your example: The length of a string and that of a list are not unrelated. Both are containers and should share a common interface part of which is getting the length. The length of a line is unrelated to the other two, but unlike the original code example it will probably have a different type (float or double instead of int) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Since **Class B does not have a "has-a" relationship to class A ..**
   so "**Composition**" should not be used.
2. You can use OOP Inheritance way as you designed. It does not break OOP  principles as you said. Class A & B are not 100% unrelated. They have common properties so OOP Inheritance way is acceptable.
   **Remember that OOP does not require inheritance of Method members.**

BUT for your case.You should duplicate Properties declaration so changes of a class does not affect the other.

```
class A
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}

class B
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public int Z;
}
```

Comment: Given those who have commented on the question, I believe that duplication is best in this scenario.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say with everything being so abstract an ill-defined, but generally, you should use inheritance when it makes sense, and not when it doesn't, and composition when it makes sense and not when it doesn't.

If A and B truly have no relationship, then it probably makes more sense to structure things differently, with the stuff you want common in its own class that is used or inherited by A and B:

```
class hasXY {
    int X;
    int Y;
}

class A : hasXY { }
class B : hasXY { int Z }
```

or

```
class A {
    hasXY  XY;
}
class B {
    hasXY  XY;
    int    Z;
}
```

Of course, this introduces extra overhead in some languages (depending on their implementation details)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you mean by "they just share properties `X` and `Y`".

Both properties are public, so they contribute to the behaviour of the class. Therefore, if the properties are really the same (have the same semantics), I would ***not*** say that the classes are unrelated. They share some behaviour, so it makes sense to use inheritance or better composition, which in most cases should be prefered.

But as you assume that `A`and `B` are unrelated, it is more likely that the properties are just unrelated variables of the same type to which you have assigned the same names. Therefore, just rename the properties in one of the classes and it will be clear that both the properties and the classes are unrelated.